# How do I set up ssl on a google vm instance, google managed certificate, and google domains which uses node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I am creating my portfolio website.  One of the pages I created was a weather app that uses the openweather API but I started reading that you should hide your API keys.  I switch the whole site over to node.js so I can use the .env file.  I can get everything working locally but when I put it on my google instance the weather API won't run saying my site is unsecure but my domain is with Google Domains and I have a SSL certificate.  I have tried for a week now to figure out what to do I have read documentation I have googled like crazy and even searched youtube.  I have set up load balancers and firewall rules.  What am I missing?

Comment: What is the problem meaning remove all the unnecessary words/descriptions and post the problem, your code and error messages. It looks like you are making an HTTP request to the weather API instead of an HTTPS request. Read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I am beyond embarrassed.  Changing the request to HTTPS worked.  Thanks again.